# Redirect after form.submit()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm working with a large program and I need to add new functionality to an existing button. Previously when the button was clicked it's operations would be performed but the page would remain in place. I need the button to continue to perform it's action but then to redirect to a new page. Currently, when I add my window.location.href after the button's action the page does redirect successfully but the button's original actions is no longer being carried out. Ignore that fact that the URL is currently hard coded, that will change.

```
            },

    submitHandler: function (form)
    {
        $('#save').attr("disabled", true);
        form.submit();
        window.location.href = "{{ dealerDomain }}/gs-vehicle/viewMyVehicle?id={{ data['id'] }}";
    }
});
```

This whole thing is inside a .validate( which is chained onto a .submit, and the only line I've added is the window.location.href. Does this help at all? window.location.href = "{{ dealerDomain }}/gs-vehicle/viewMyVehicle?id={{ data['id'] }}";

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more information, and you should provide us with more code in order to give you a better answer

Comment: What is this part "`window.location.href = 'http...?id=...';`

Comment: You should provide more code than this. Please take a look at the ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Your code is incomplete by the way.

Comment: *"but the button's original actions is no longer being carried out"* what does that mean?

Comment: You can use callback, `$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {}`

Comment: Or you can execute the funciton in ajax call back `$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: "form_handler.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        // callback code here
       }
    })
`

Comment: This whole thing is inside a .validate( which is chained onto a .submit, and the only line I've added is the window.location.href. Does this help at all?

window.location.href = "{{ dealerDomain }}/gs-vehicle/viewMyVehicle?id={{ data['id'] }}";

Comment: You can not do two actions that cause the page to redirect. If you want the page to redirect, why is the form submission not redirecting?

Comment: As @epascarello said, the place that is submitting the form can redirect it once it finishes processing the form. Otherwise, you can submit a`POST` using `fetch` and redirect in the callback.